# What is the max span that can be supported by 2x4 floor joists?

Tags: framing, joists, uk

We had old 2x4 floor joists sitting in our bathroom that we ripped out as they were rotten and falling apart.

2x4 is ideally our limit of thickness, and I was thinking of having 4 or 5 2x4 joists going from one end of the wall to another (147cm / 58") bolted to a 2x4or 2x6 (not sure which one) bearer against all 4 walls. The bearers will be thunderbolted to the brick walls and joist hangers will be used for the 2 by 4s.

I have a very poorly drawn picture from myself to illustrate the 2 by 4 joists. We're thinking about putting the joists 30cm (12") OC.

How much weight can this take? Is this adequate for a room that is 7 ft 9 inches?

Based in the UK.

[image]

See a video of the floor.

https://streamable.com/2wbrxk

Comment: Load capacity reduces as length increases.

Comment: 147cm is only 58", so the span isn't particularly long. 30cm is 12" which is unusually narrow for floor joists, but _could_ help make up (by adding additional support) for the smaller than usual joist dimensions. You say 2x4 is "ideally limit of thickness" is that because the 2x4s are already sitting on a sub-floor of some sort?

Comment: Also, what does "thunderbolted" to the wall mean? I'm envisioning using some cables for Apple's favorite connector to hold them to the wall, but I'm pretty certain that's not what you mean. ;)

Comment: Haha, sorry maybe thunderbolt isn’t the right term but essentially just bolted to the wall. The floor was previous 2 x 4 length ways with 2 2 by 4s horizontally sitting on a couple of bricks either side of the wall. Because of the soil pipe and where it’s located, we don’t want to box, we want enough fall so that poop goes down properly, and we don’t want to cut joists. Hence the idea of having it like this. The span is narrow but hoped that it would reinforce it a bit?

Comment: The joists that we’re going the opposite direction to what I drew were notched and sitting on slate. But we want them this way and attached to the bearer with the joist hangers. Whether the bearer can be 2 x 6 or has to be 2 x 4 because the joists will be I don’t know.

Comment: 2x4s aren't appropriate as joists for anything larger than a stairway landing, and even then I'd use 2x6. Why is 2x4 your limit?

Comment: The soil pipe is the issue and I’m thinking how to redirect the soil pipe without boxing and keeping everything under the floor

Comment: Why are 2 x 4s not appropriate anyway?

Comment: The whole bungalow is essentially made of 2 by 4 floor joists. These are true 2 by 4 btw and not the 1.5 by 3.5 you get nowadays

Comment: Current building regs give max span distance for 4 x 2 joists as 6' 4" for C16 and 7ft for C24. So our is just 8 inches above that 7ft 8 inches is brick to brick not wall to wall (there will be stud walls and waterproof boards and tiles), which means the floor would be about 7ft and an inch walking space. So idk..

Comment: It might be helpful to include a few pics of your actual space. An overview pic or two showing the whole area, then some closeups with a ruler showing measurements of various details that you think are important. There are calculators all over the web that will convert cm to in, so no need to worry what unit your ruler is in.

Comment: I posted a video if that helps

Comment: In your other question (*on which i provided an answer*) it was suggested that the joists would be resting on the concrete slab. If not then rip 2"x 6"s down (*or whatever lumber is required to get your dimensions*) so that they rest on the slab. Or put sleepers down on the slab for the joist to sit on. This way the slab is doing the supporting.

Comment: Thanks Alaska Man, we are going up and down in terms of what is the best way with the room size we have and all the caveats there is to it. Think we are gonna leave the toilet in the corner of the room. Thing is we can't go above 2 by 4 because of the concrete slab separating the bricks, so we have to go with 2 by 4s.

Comment: Is it just me or when watching the video is anyone else confused why 2x6s wouldn't fit?

Comment: We are going by 2 by 6s. Will just have to sacrifice where the toilet goes as we want it all underground!

Answer (score 2):

When you ask for the maximum span of a 2x4 floor joist at 12” on center, there are many issues. We design from the top down and build from the bottom up.

1. Your subfloor must be rated to span from joist to joist. If you use 12” spacing then a 1/2” thick board is acceptable, but at 16” spacing you should use 5/8” plywood and for 24” spacing then use 3/4” thick plywood.  This is based on supporting 15 lbs. per square foot of Dead Load and 65 lbs. per square foot of Live Load. (This is higher than normal, but will allow you to use a tile floor without deflecting too much.)
2. The maximum span for joists depends on species and grade. I’ll assume an average grade of Number 1 (C16). C16 is economical to use and easy to find. So, for 2x4 at 12” oc the maximum span is about 7’-6”, which is about the distance you need. (If you go to C24 it could be longer.) Remember, spans are measured from face of support to face of support.
3. Joist hangers are also rated. Finding a hanger that will accept a true 2” wide joist will be difficult. Simpson has a hanger and is rated for 600 lbs., which is fine for your application.
4. Using a perimeter ledger could require a 2x6, because you need 4 times the bolt diameter. A 1/2” bolt would require an edge distance of 2”. A 1/2” bolt will need to be about 12” on center to support your load.

Comment: Hey Lee :), thanks for your comment! When you say face of support to face of support, what do you mean? Bit of a noob with terminology. Also, so this is technically achievable with 2 by 6 ledgers, can I have the ledgers on 2 opposite walls and not all 4? Just wondering because it would be hard to get a bearer under where the door is as there’s no much empty space from the bricks being knocked out... so not sure what to do about that.

Comment: And can this also be without concrete blocks under the ledgers? Or do you recommend I add them?

Comment: Span length means you can subtract the widths of the ledgers. Yes, 2x6 ledgers are acceptable and they can be on just 2 walls. If adequately bolted then the ledgers do not need concrete blocks.

Comment: 2x4 at *12” oc* (!) the maximum span is about **7’-6”** - at 16" oc, I'm guessing 4' or less, but either way I wouldn't go any further just on principle.