# 12x12 shed with 2x4 subfloor frame on 4x4 skids

Tags: floor, shed

I am building a 12x12 shed on 4ea treated 4x4 skids with a subfloor using treated 2x4's on 16" centers, and 3/4 plywood floor. I want to use 2x4's to keep the shed to ground level lower. From what I have been reading, a 2x4 can support the 4ft spread between the 4x4 skids. Anyone see an issue with this?
thanks
Dean

Comment: Dead load rating is important for something like a shed. Google "floor joist span table" if you haven't done so already. You should probably consult an engineer. Check out https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/210743/42053. Play around with this [calculator](https://awc.org/calculators/span-options-calculator-for-wood-joists-and-rafters/)

Comment: monkeyzeus , Thanks for the calculator. According to it, I can go 6ft 1in span on 16in centers. I will only be going just under 4ft. Seems it will be find

Comment: Sure, I am not an engineer. I will not lose sleep if your shed turns out to have sagging floors. When in doubt, overengineer. I would go for 6 skids.

Comment: Or 2x6 joists. The extra 2" of height shouldn't matter much if you're building a ramp. If it's a step up, then yeah, I can see where that might make a difference.

Comment: Which way are the 4x2s? To keep the floor lower, you *could* put them 2" high - in which case they could be sawn lengthways and 16" centres would probably still be good. Just an idea.

Comment: Tim - The 2x4's would be running across the 4x4's. I think it would be supported enough, but Monkeyzeus makes me not what to use them because my floor COULD SAG. Looks like I am just going to have to build a step and or a ramp for my riding mower.